# Optional render of childlren

Tags: reactjs

I have a component that contains data from an endpoint. I show a spinner as long as the data is not yet ready.

```js
const UserName = () => {
  const {data: user, isLoading} = Client.query('user')
  return (
    <div>
      {
        isLoading
        ?
        <Spinner />
        :
        <div>
          {user.name}
        </div>
      }
    </div>
  );
}
```

this was working fine as it was. However i wanted to extract this logic into a separate component so that i have shared behavior for all unloaded content. And so that all spinners will always look the same

I tried doing the following:

```js
const DynamicContent = ({isLoading, children}) => {
  if(isLoading){
    return <Spinner />
  } else {
    return children
  }
}

const UserName = () => {
  const {data: user, isLoading} = Client.query('user')
  return (
    <DynamicContent isLoading={isLoading}>
        <div>
          {user.name}
        </div>
    </DynamicContent>
  );
}
```

Now this doesn't work because the user has not been defined when the component renders for the first time so i get a nullpointer on `user.name`.

I suspect that this happens because the content being passed as children to my `DynamicContent` gets calculated first.

How would i go about conditionally rendering content passed as children. Is there a way i can make the evaluation the children passed to the component lazy?

EDIT: Setting a default value to the user is not an option in my real case because the object returned from the endpoint is a deeply nested object on which i'd access attributes like `user.x.y.z`.

I could add nullchecks everywhere an attribute from the user is accessed but this gets ugly fast.

I'm looking for a way that allows me to lazily interpret the content of the child component when passing it to the `DynamicContent` one. Something along the lines of:

```
const UserName = () => {
  const {data: user, isLoading} = Client.query('user')
  return (
    <DynamicContent isLoading={isLoading}>
        <Lazy>
          <div>
            {user.address.country.name}
          </div>
        </Lazy>
    </DynamicContent>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way to give the `user` a default empty value as:

```
const UserName = () => {
  const {data: user = {}, isLoading} = Client.query('user')
  return (
   <DynamicContent isLoading={isLoading}>
     <div>
      {user.name}
     </div>
   </DynamicContent>
  );
}
```

the value will be overridden when the api returns the user.

Other way can be to actually check if the object is not null before accessing values from it.

`typescript` do it by using like `user?.name`
`lodash` has similar utility [get](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#get) from an object if present.

Or you can always right your own utility for the same.

Comment: using a default value is not really possible in my real case because the data is deeply nested so transitive attributes would also result in nullpointers. 
I could try the `.get` from lodash but this would be similar to nullchecks throughout the component.
I was looking more for something that allows me to lazily interpret the content of the children passed to a component

Comment: I ended up using lodash's `get` function and that worked fine. even though this wasn't the answer i was looking for it does the trick for now so i'll accept this until something better comes up.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this...i hope it would help you to understand the way.

```
export default function UserName(){
  let user = {
    name: 'John'
  }
  return (
    <DynamicContent isLoading={true}>
        <div>
         <h1>Hello {user.name}</h1>
        </div>
    </DynamicContent>
  );
}
const DynamicContent = ({isLoading, children}) => {
  if(isLoading){
    return <Spinner />
  } else {
    return children
  }
}
const Spinner = () => <h3>Loading...</h3>
```

> I passed true to isLoading. you can try putting your required condition.

[Live demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/children-component-p6ft5?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: You are defaulting the user object to some set value first which makes sense. but the object in my real case (this one was a simplified example) is a lot more complex and not as easy to set a sensible default for. It also contains nested attributes like `user.address.country.name` or something which would make this solution fail

Answer (score 0):

This might give you come more clarity of how you can use it

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function UserName() {
  const [user] = useState({
    name:'John'
  })
  const [isLoading,setisLoading] = useState(true)

  useEffect(()=>{
    setTimeout(()=>{
      setisLoading(false)
    },3000)
  },[])

  return (
    <DynamicContent isLoading={isLoading}>
      <div>
        <h1>Hello {user.name}</h1>
      </div>
    </DynamicContent>
  );
}
const DynamicContent = ({ isLoading, children }) => {
  if (isLoading) {
    return <Spinner />;
  } else {
    return children;
  }
};
const Spinner = () => <h3>Loading...</h3>;
```

[Here is the working demo:-](https://codesandbox.io/s/spinner-example-j76qk)

Comment: This works because `user` has a default value that can be accessed. In my real example this is not easily possible because the user object is deeply nested and i access nested attributes like `user.x.y.z`.

Comment: then you can add a condition whether if `user.x.y.z!==undefined ?user.x.y.z: ' ' `

Comment: That doesn't work if my user objects default value is `{}` since it will access `x` on `{}` which is undefined and then access `y` on undefined which gives an error. it doesn't get to the `!==undefined` check.
So i'd have to create a default object of `{x: {y: {}}` at the very least, and since the user object returned from the backend is quite complex this is not very clean

Comment: What case it might be is the object may be empty `{}` or it maybe have `user.x.y.z` so what you can do is `Object.keys(user).length !==0 ? user.x.y.z : ''`